MCP73831-2 Stat Pin
The idea is to drive two Leds (one at a time) with STAT output from the MCP73831-2
Red when charging.
Green when charge is complete.
The Stat pin has three states:
High Z - shutdown / No battery present
Low - during charge
High - when charge is complete
This is what I did: 
I connected a PSU instead of the battery to test the circuit and the result is
red on all the time and green goes off at 4.1V (the version I have,should be 4.2V end of charge, but this is something else I need to check), defintely not the result I was looking for :)

Have you double checked the pins on the LED? The schematic symbol does not match the physical layout. STAT can also source 35 mA so you could ditch the transistor and have STAT drive the green LED directly.

The LED pins, as per datasheet, are correct. 1, 3, 5 are BRG anode and 2, 4, 6 are BRG cathode. How can I drive two LEDs but having only one on per state without the BJT?

Here is one concept. The gate is a ST type and is wired to work as a relaxation oscillator at perhaps 200Hz. When the pin is high Z, neither LED is on (save perhaps a bit of light due to capacitance - to be tested) and if the pin is high or low one or the other LED will be on with about 50% duty cycle (but too fast to notice any flicker).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

The low output of the STAT pin has a max of 1V, which means, since the 2N3904 base starts conducting around 0.7V, even the Low logical state for this pin produces an ON state for the Red LED, which is not what you want.
If you add a 3.3K ohm resistor from the junction between the 6.8K resistor and the base of the 2N3904, I believe that it should fix your problem.
Below shows a LTspice XVII simulation of the current situation on the left, and my proposed solution on the right, with R3, the resistor to be added circled.


I have tried all values from 680R to about 4.2K without success. The green LED, which is now by the way connected to R11, stays always ON
